# Disable Rules for Firebase Real-Time Database for Android Development Access Firebase Admin Sdk

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have found out that if we disable the rule Firebase Real-Time database, we still can access for website developement by using Firebase Admin SDK. But how about Android development? I have some cases that I need to disable the rules.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "false",  // 2021-6-22
    ".write": "false",  // 2021-6-22
  }
}
```

I have found out this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup?authuser=0#initialize-sdk
Tried already but error:

```
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.3.0 (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.3.0)
```

Comment: You are using Admin SDK on website frontend? 0_o

Comment: @DimaRostopira yes, python as backend.

Comment: You have to setup proper rules, or call you python backend from Android app, there is no easy way. However, the whole idea of firebase (backend-as-a-service) is to avoid writing your own backend

Comment: @DimaRostopira what did you mean is first option is proper rules. 2nd option is android studio use Retrofit connect with backend python?

Comment: Proper rules is something beyond true/false (= The second option you got right, but I wouldn't recommend

Comment: Start reading from here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security

Comment: @DimaRostopira I forgot the whole main idea Firebase is avoid backend. But the Firebase  Admin Sdk is what for?

Comment: It's for cases when existing Firebase features are not enough

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233017/discussion-between-dima-rostopira-and-ticherhaz-freepalestine).

Comment: When you are using Firebase Admin SDK, you are bypassing the security rules, however, this cannot be done from an Android app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The admin sdk is designed as a backend solution with service credentials that bypass Security Rules as a whole by connecting to GCP directly. It isn't advised to offer this to client access for security reasons.

as such, it is not possible to integrate Security Rules against the Admin sdk, a solution is to run requests through cloud functions or another rest server to validate user requests.